# problem with catkin and pcl_ros

Tags: ros, devel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
after give from terminal the catkin_make command, it give an error that say:

```
CMake Error at /home/jacopo/catkin_ws/devel/share/pcl_ros/cmake/pcl_rosConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'pcl_ros' specifies '/usr/include/ni' as an include dir, which is
  not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '/home/jacopo/catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl-indigo-devel/pcl_ros//usr/include/ni'.
```

i've found in the web that the manual removing of the `/usr/include/ni` from the `/opt/ros/hydro/share/pcl_ros/cmake/pcl_rosConfig.cmake` can solve the problem.
after removing it, you could see that the error is no more from that directory, but from the devel directory of catkin...
how i can solve that problem??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203688/problem-with-catkin-and-pcl_ros/) by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're missing dependencies. Run

> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro [hydro/indigo] -y

on your workspace, using the appropriate distro tag.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-02-24**:
i cannot understand what from-paths src and --ignore-src -- means
can you explain well or link some pages? cause i really cannot understand what you'd write.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-02-24**:
rosdep has built in documentation. Run `rosdep install -h`